# Find Space In String and Delete It

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula that I can use to find a space after a comma, within a cell, and delete that space. The space will be dynamically located within the string as the strings are names.

**For example, I need the following names to change from this:**

Redfield, Chris

Doe, Jane R

Doe, Johnathan

Person, Random F

**To this:**

Redfield,Chris

Doe,Jane R

Doe,Johnathan

Person,Random F

Hopefully that makes sense. I need this so I can compare names from one sheet to another. I have tried LEN, RIGHT & FIND, and TRIM formulas, and different combinations of them, but I think I am missing something because I have not had any luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REPLACE with FIND:

```
=REPLACE($A$1,FIND(", ",$A$1),2,",")
```

Finds the position of ", " and replaces those two characters with one: ",".

Comment: Perfect. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Regardless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose the easiest solution is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",",")
```

[Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

In Excel Help you should find this page and study the various functions.

[image]